# How would I create a SMOTE pipeline step for text classification, when the resampling method does not work with text?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, text-classification, topic-modeling

I have a multi-label classification problem with a huge class imbalance problem as such I would like to create a pipeline step with SMOTE but as the X is basically text and the Y is an array of 1s and 0s for said label, I can't just plug in SMOTE() this way as it needs both a fit and transform.

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('smote', SMOTE()), 
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()), 
    ('ss', StandardScaler(with_mean=False)), 
    ('clf', model),
])
```

Comment: I think `SMOTE` comes with it's own Pipeline subclass which might be worth looking into (at the very least for examples), but wouldn't `smote` come after `vect` and `tfidf`?

Comment: Yes, SMOTE has its own pipeline, which must be used. In addition to that, SMOTE will come down in the pipeline, just before your `model`. Need some more information, like which tutorial are you following for this, some samples of the data, etc

Comment: You're absolutely right about the SMOTE, I'm not following a tutorial in particular just doing text classification on my X which is just a bunch of articles in text and y which is a label or topic for the article. The pipeline plugs into a GridSearchCV which is where I'm having issues since the pipeline subclass of SMOTE does not have the fit and transform of a pipeline that can be plugged into Gridsearch.

Comment: maybe you would like to take a look on sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer, I'm not sure if it will return the new Ys though

Answer (score 4):

The current version of imbalanced-learn comes with it's own [pipeline](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html). You should be able to incorporate it in your sklearn pipeline. You just need to add this line after your sklearn imports, make sure it overides the sklearn version of pipeline if previously imported, and just use it like how you would use a sklearn pipeline.

```
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have in mind: the imbalanced-learn package works for multi-class projects, but not for multi-label ones, error messages will be thrown if you use it.

```
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline 

text_pipeline = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize, 
                                  ngram_range=(1,2),
                                  max_df=0.75)), 
                          ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(sublinear_tf=True))])
pipeline = Pipeline([('features', FeatureUnion([('text_pipeline', text_pipeline)])),
                     ('clf', MultiOutputClassifier(LogisticRegression(solver='saga',
                                                                      multi_class='auto',
                                                                      max_iter=500,
                                                                      class_weight='balanced',
                                                                      n_jobs=-1, random_state=FIXED_SEED)))])
```

Comment: Could you maybe add some source to support your statement? It would give more value to your answer.

Comment: @Corentin sorry, I should have done this. The dataset is the disaster messages one from figure 8, which is highly imbalanced and a multi-class, multi-label classification task. After some cleaning the remaining English messages are mapped to a set of target category labels. I wanted to use the imblearn pipeline for e.g.

Comment: @Corentin, here is a code example (ups, ugly format) ...
`from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline  
pipeline = Pipeline([  
    ('features', FeatureUnion([  
        ('text_pipeline', Pipeline([   
            ('vect', CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize, ngram_range=(1,2), max_df=0.75)),    
            ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(sublinear_tf=True)),    
        ]))               
    ])),     
    ('clf', MultiOutputClassifier(LogisticRegression(solver='saga', multi_class='auto',    
            max_iter=500, class_weight='balanced', n_jobs=-1, random_state=FIXED_SEED)))  
])`